# One time refresh for $_POST in php

Tags: php, mysql

Suppose I have a form in page_1 like this

```
<form action="page_2.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="text">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

And in page_2, it is like

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    $q = mysqli_query("INSERT INTO sample_table VALUES('$_POST[text]')",$database_connect);

}
```

The problem of this code is, it will work fine for the first time. But if a user refreshes page_2, then the same data will be inserted in my database table 'sample_table' again and again by creating a new row each time. But I want my user to insert the data in my database for only first time he clicks on 'submit' button. And later, if he refreshes page_2, data will not be added in my database table again and again. How can this be done?

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: I'm new in this sector. Can you give me an example how to use queries?

Comment: It's all in the links in that comment. The PHP manual and associated comments go into a great deal of detail.

Comment: Post redirect to Get.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to prevent duplicated submissions you need to add another column to your table with some kind of unique key. If you add a `UNIQUE` constraint to this column then duplicated inserts will be rejected by the database.

Populating this on the form with a [UUID-type value](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php) when rendering the form is the typical way of doing this.

If you're looking to reject exactly duplicated submissions you can skip the UUID part and use something like a SHA256 hash of the content instead. These index nicely with `UNIQUE`.

Answer (score 0):

If your different users are not going to insert the same data, you can query the database with the text value and see if it exists. Place all data into seperate variables also

Comment: Not only different user, but also same user can post same info again. But I want the data to be inserted in my database for only the first time user clicks on submit button. To insert the data again, the user has to go back to the form and click on submit again.

Comment: Okay, so if you want that data only entered once, no matter which user enters it, you only want it in once, you can query your database to check if that data already exists, if it does, you can code it so it doesnt update again, using an if statement

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want the data to be entered again. Then add a line that forces the user back to the previous page after submitting the form.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

$q = mysqli_query("INSERT INTO sample_table VALUES('$_POST[text]')",$database_connect);

header("Location: page_1.php");
}
```